# How use a variable List<Object> that refers more CONSTANT List<Object>

Tags: android, list, object, clone, constants

1. Opening the activity there is the list with the first listView. The list is a copy of a Constant list copied with `new ArrayList<>(Constants.FIRST)`.
2. I clear the (activity) list and refer to the second list with `list = new ArrayList(Constants.SECOND);`, notify the adapter but is empty.
3. Return back to the first list the list is again empty.

This is the code that I used

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private List<Object> list; //tried also... = new ArrayList<>;
    private boolean boo;
    private ObjectAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_view);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list = new ArrayList<>(Constants.FIRST);
        adapter = new ObjectAdapter(this, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (boo){
                   newIntent(position);
                }
                else {
                    secondList(position);
                }
            }
        });
    }
public void newIntent(int position){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    }

    public void secondList(int position){
        list.clear();
        list = new ArrayList<>(Constants.SECOND);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        boo = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (boo) {list.clear(); list = new ArrayList<>(Constants.FIRST); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); boo=false;}
        else {finish();}
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }

        return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
    }
}
```

And this is the constant List

```
public interface Constants {

    List<Object> FIRST= new ArrayList<Object>(){{
        add (new Object(0, 1, "Good"));
        add (new Object(1, 1, "Ok"));

    List<Object> SECOND= new ArrayList<Object>(){{
        add (new Object(0, 2, "First"));
        add (new Object(1, 2, "Second"));
```

Comment: Does this line `private List<Object> list; //tried also... = new ArrayList<>;` refer to `lista`? Where is `lista` declared? I'm not sure what you try to achieve. Do you want to have those 4 objects from your `interface Constants` in `lista`?

Comment: Initially you have set the listAdapter to null !  
`adapter = new ObjectAdapter(this, list);`  
and here `list` is empty you didn't put anything in it.  
when you change `lista` it doesn't affect the adapter

Comment: Sorry I wrong to write "lista" here, the "list" is instantiated correctly. The constants contain 2 list with 200 objects but I simplified the code here